# label pandas header with an index name

Tags: pandas, plotly

i try to run this code, to generate a plot with plotly express.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,0,0], [1,1,1,0,1],
                   [1,1,0,1,0], [0,1,1,1,1]])

##example by plotly
#https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/
#fig = px.line(df, facet_col="company", facet_col_wrap=2)

fig = px.area(df, facet_col_wrap=2) #works but not as expected
#fig = px.area(df,facet_col="???", facet_col_wrap=2) #should be the solution, but "???" is missing

fig.show(renderer="browser")
```

the example of plolty (https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/) has a labeled header ("company"), which is called with the facet_col. id don't know how to insert a label for my df header. i expect to plot the dataframe as in the example from plotly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your data frame into appropriate structure for plotly express

- `unstack()` to transform columns into rows in index
- `reset_index()` to make index columns, plus restore original row index with `set_index()`
- now you have a structure to use parameters to `px.line()`

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,0,0], [1,1,1,0,1],
                   [1,1,0,1,0], [0,1,1,1,1]])

px.area(df.unstack().to_frame().reset_index().set_index("level_0"), facet_col="level_1", facet_col_wrap=2)
```

[image]